# Running windows command in golang

Tags: windows, go, cmd

I have seen the existing solutions to run a windows command from a Golang program but none works for me.
My aim is to open a `.png` file from the go program.

**Below is sample program. It does not open the image file. I am just trying with `dir` for testing.**

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-lah")
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
        cmd = exec.Command("cmd", "dir")
    }
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

I have also tried `cmd = exec.Command("dir")` in line 13. 
The program just exists without any error or output. Seems like a successful execution as there is no error being shown to me. I tried a few variations but no success.

I am using VSCode and tried running this program through built-in `cmd` and `wsl` in VSCode. **When I use `wsl` to run the program, it shows the output of `ls -lah` but nothing for cmd**.
I don't know if there is some way to direct windows output.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you ran `cmd dir` at a prompt in Windows, would it work?

Comment: It will not but I also tried cmd = exec.Command("dir") as well. Brits explanation clears it. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cmd.exe is the windows command interpreter; if you wish to pass it a command to run you need to use the /c parameter - e.g. `cmd /c dir`. If you enter `cmd dir` at a command prompt you will get the same result as your current go application (except that the cmd prompt will not automatically close due to the lack of stdin). If you run `cmd /?` this is explained as:

> /C      Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

So to fix your application use the following:

`cmd = exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "dir")`

An alternative way of doing this is to pass the command in via stdin:

```
cmd := exec.Command("cmd")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
go func() {
    defer stdin.Close()
    io.WriteString(stdin, "dir\n")
}()
err = cmd.Run()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
}
```

A simple way to open your BMP file is `cmd = exec.Command("explorer.exe", "test.bmp")` (this will open it with whatever the default application is).

Note: The reason you need to run `cmd` in the first place is that `dir` is an internal command provided by `cmd.exe` (if you run `dir dir.* /s` in the windows folder you won't find anything because there is no `dir.exe` or similar; its embedded in `cmd.exe`).

Note2: If you are were running ls/dir in this way to get the contents of a folder (rather than as an example) then [ioutil.ReadDir](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir) is a better option.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. It clears my confusion as well works.

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Brits, the error seems to manifest only when a Windows internal command is request. So, to circumvent the check done on the file path, I created a local batch file with the same name as the Windows internal command, e.g. if I wanted to run an "ECHO" command, I can create a echo.bat file that contains "@ECHO %1". Just tested and the same code is now working on both Windows and Linux, e.g.:

```golang
    cmd := exec.Command(os.Args[1], os.Args[2:]...)

    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    cmd.Run()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer the answer youre talking about. When you say "above" it can be misleading as other answers can be added and get more upvotes than yours. Or your answer can become the answer and go to the top.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just made an edit to clarify.